# Which part of Android directories contains so-called proprietary blobs?

Tags: file-system, lineageos, aosp

When building AOSP ([Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/)) or [LineageOS](https://lineageos.org/), there is a tool named breakfast. It downloads proprietary blobs and integrates them to the source tree.

I have read [this article](https://wiki.lineageos.org/proprietary_blobs.html), does it mean all of the blobs are under  `/system/vendor/` directory?

Do those binary files also exist in Android filesystem? And where are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, binary blobs are part of Android filesystem. Android can't boot without them as they are kind of hardware drivers for the device. Most of those are found under `/vendor/lib(64)`, some also under `/system`, `/etc` and `/bin`. Before [Android Treble](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/faster-adoption-with-project-treble.html), `/vendor` wasn't necessarily a partition but a symlink to `/system/vendor` directory. Starting with Oreo, `/vendor` is a partition, containing all content related to `OEM` and `SoC` vendor. Most of the blobs are executable files or libraries, run as independent services on boot. See this sample [proprietary-files](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_xiaomi_mido/blob/lineage-16.0/proprietary-files.txt) list.

In addition to that, the first partition (usually labeled `modem`) on eMMC contains Radio/RIL related firmware. Another partition `dsp` contains Qualcomm's *Digital Signal Processor* related binaries. They aren't built with ROM but are part of Android [filesystem tree](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=75905976&postcount=3), mounted at `(/vendor)/firmware` and `(/vendor)/dsp`. Their execution is isolated from the rest of the device.

Many partition related to bootloaders are in themselves complete binaries, such as `aboot`, `sbl`, `rpm`, `tz`, `cmnlib`, `devcfg`, `keymaster`, `lksecapp` on Qualcomm devices. Those aren't mountable filesystem, but directly executed by bootloaders during boot process. All of them are proprietary binary blobs; the closed-source part of Android devices.

**PS:**
Android (a superset of AOSP) isn't a generic OS which can be installed on any hardware like we do on PCs. *Support for the hardware is locked down to proprietary binaries ([HALs](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture)) by the OEM and/or silicon vendors.* So the binary blobs are critical, and the open-source AOSP (including modified Linux kernel source provided by Google) is of no use without hardware drivers. And the manufacturers rarely document the working of their hardware so that developers like [Replicant](https://replicant.us/) can implement an open source driver. There is very small set of hardware components on Android devices that you can expect to be handled directly by making syscalls to kernel as is the case on PCs. The only notable addition by SoC vendors / OEMs to generic kernel source already modified by Google <sup>([1](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/android-common), [2](https://elinux.org/Android_Kernel_Features#List_of_kernel_features_unique_to_Android))</sup> is the handling of [non-discoverable devices](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/modular-kernels) (defining device nodes). Rest of the hardware related stuffed is handled in userspace through binary blobs.

**Further reading:**

- [Android Device Partitions and Filesystems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565)
- [Android and Linux Kernel Drivers](http://hiqes.com/android-linux-kernel-drivers/)
- [Android HAL and Device driver architecture](https://www.e-consystems.com/blog/system-on-module-SOM/android-hal-and-device-driver-architecture/)