# Are multiple-users protected from each other differently than apps?

Tags: security, linux, multi-user

I confess that I come from the happy world of unix computers, and am used to the concept of user accounts and hence group `gid`s and userids `uid`s. For the occasional usage of an untrusted app (i.e. **whatsapp/facebook**) I have created another user profile for many reasons, but mostly because I wanted to reduce any potential access **whatsapp/facebook** might gain with regards to my main account.

Now the strange thing is that to the best of my understanding the protection mechanism of AOSP, relies on assigning a actually user ids to individual apps, as with those `uid`, the apps can be limited using that the underlying `linux` kernel provides *Unix Discretionary Access Controls* (i.e. file accesss dependent on `uid` and `gid`).

My question is if I am misleading myself that AOSP provides any stronger protection with regards to multi-users (in between the accounts) than it does with regards to the various apps to each other?

Comment: I don't understand Linux part but this probably should help you https://android.stackexchange.com/q/201826/131553

Answer (score 8):

### PRIVACY: ANDROID VS. *NIX:

**PROTECTION:**

**Being protected** has a very vast meaning, varying for persons and situations. Comparing Android with *NIX systems, admittedly the former offers more isolation between apps and a more fine-grained control over permissions. Quick examples:

- On PC, user is trusting all the processes / apps running under same    UID (usually a human user) <sup>([1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180555/why-is-root-security-enforced-but-home-typically-unprotected/180557#180557))</sup>. On Android it's not the case; every app is a different user to have possibly minimum influence on other apps.
- A PC user can easily get **superuser** / administrator rights, an Android user cannot <sup>([2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207623/what-special-privileges-system-xbin-su-does-have-w-r-t-root-access/207902#207902))</sup>.

The demand and reason are obvious:

- **Privacy matters more** because a phone is a `24/7` *inevitable* assistant as well as a perfect **spy** equipped with all necessary hardware tools.
- And **the reason** is that it's easy to implement a more restrictive environment on a less customizable device.

Traditional *NIX DAC dates back to the early days of personal computing, when the **isolation** was only focused between users (UID's/GID's), not between processes / apps. Because there were no closed-source **paid apps** in stores from *unknown* developers; not much personal data to be protected from **malicious processes**; no user **profiling**, targeted **advertisement**, trackers, analytics, **ransomware** and so on.

**SECURITY MECHANISMS:**

***NIX DAC** was found insufficient particularly with internet revolution, hence superuser privileges were divided into **capabilities** and new sandboxing mechanisms were introduced at kernel level, including **MAC** and **namespaces**. Android makes use of all of them more or less, they control which resources a process can access on device. Also, **cgroups** control how much resources a process can use. But even then, these security mechanisms weren't enough to **minutely lock-down the apps**, so a number of controls are handled within Android's own framework (in userspace). Android's [system_server](https://www.slideshare.net/opersys/understanding-the-android-system-server) has more services running inside it than native services. When I say *"mechanisms weren't enough"*, concern is not only to design an ecosystem to protect **user's privacy / security**, but also to protect Google's business model as well as of app developers.

**PC VS. ANDROID:**

It should also be noted that there is no **standardization** in Android (rather in embedded) world unlike PC's. Android uses a modified Linux kernel, which doesn't fully handle hardware in **kernel** space, instead relies on a number of userspace **closed source** processes from SoC / OEM vendors <sup>([3](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207760/218526))</sup>, which interact with other processes and hardware drivers using Android-specific [binder / HAL mechanism](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/07/shut-hal-up.html). So *NIX DAC, which is heavily based on ***everything is a file*** philosophy, doesn't seem to work very far. A hardware device is no more simply a file in `/dev` which can be accessed by adding the app process to some supplementary group, there are layers of **APIs** and **IPCs** involved (Java and native).

However Android does take advantage of Linux kernel's robust frameworks e.g. DAC. Apps' **internet connectivity** is controlled by adding them to a special supplementary group `3003`. See: [How Android's permissions mapping with UIDs/GIDs works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208523/how-androids-permissions-mapping-with-uids-gids-works/208982#208982)

### WHAT SHOULD BE PROTECTED ON ANDROID:

Coming to user's granular control over security / privacy on Android device, a few things one can be concerned about are who can:

- Access personal data (pictures, documents, videos, backups etc.)
- Get accounts information (added by apps including Google)
- Get read/write access to data from content providers like:

  - Contacts
  - Call log
  - Messages
- Read user / device identifiers (MAC address, IMEI, Android ID etc.)
- Read usage statistics
- Find installed apps
- Access camera, record audio/video
- Make calls, send messages
- Get internet connectivity
- Get device location
- Run in background (e.g. surveillance or tracking apps)

And so on.

### APP PERMISSIONS AND SANDBOXING:

Android divides its [protected APIs](https://source.android.com/security/overview/app-security#the-android-permission-model-accessing-protected-apis) in different [Protection Levels](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217522/218526). Apps' access to most of the above resources is either controlled by [manifest permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) or user has **no control** over them.

- For instance you can't restrict an app's access to internet without using some third party firewall. Every app which requests for `INTERNET` permission is granted at installation time, you can't remove its supplementary group `AID_INET (3003)`.
- Similarly `READ_CONTACTS` and `GET_ACCOUNTS` permissions belong to same group and are controlled with same toggle switch on GUI.
- And you can't deny an app running in background unless you use Android's hidden permissions manager: [AppOps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager).
- And that's not the end. If you want more fine-grained control over permissions e.g. revoking an app's ability to [getInstalledApplications](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstalledApplications(int)), you need some heavy framework modifier like [Xposed](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed) and [XPrivacy](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacyLua).

Every app is assigned a unique UID/GID at installation time and it runs inside its own stance of **Virtual Machine**, forked by `zygote`. DAC enforced to filesystems, apps are bound to access only their own directories, particularly on internal storage (`/data/user/<UserId>/<pkg_name>`), private/public external storage (`/data/media/<UserId>`) and procfs (`/proc/self/` etc.).

DAC sandboxing is also supplemented by MAC, e.g. **SELinux policy** won't allow apps to read `/proc/stat` and `rootfs (/)` (but allow them to read other app's data directory <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r35/private/untrusted_app_all.te#29))</sup> ;). On the other hand `/data/misc/profiles/cur/<UserId>/<pkg_name>` is allowed by DAC but restricted by SELinux.

### MULTIPLE USERS ISOLATION:

An XYZ app in primary user account with UID/GID `10500` can access it's private data/settings/databases in `/data/user/0/<com.xyz>` but not in secondary user account because `/data/user/xx/<com.xyz>` has UID/GID owner `xx10500` where `xx` is [UserID](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/managed-profiles#settings). How DAC controls access to `/sdcard` (external storage) is explained in [What is the “u#_everybody” UID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210159/218526)

Basic sandboxing **isolation exists between apps** whether those are from same or different users. But a notable additional isolation between apps of different user accounts / profiles is the **separate shared storage** (i.e. `/sdcard`), which is a benefit obviously if you don't trust the app. It's because an app has access either only to its private directories, or to whole external storage. This problem of **too open public files** is being controlled through Android Q's privacy change: [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/scoped-storage).

This isolation between apps of different user accounts / profiles also exists at **Java framework** level. For instance in our above example, `getInstalledApplications` *“returns a list of all application packages that are installed for the **current user**”* only. So an app won't be able to find out what apps you have installed on other user account / profile.

Since the installed apps' data is isolated, the stock Android's **content providers** (which are also system apps) are also isolated. So the `contacts`, `call logs`, `calendars`, `messages`, `media` (list of files on external storage) etc. aren't shared among users.

Other things which are isolated between users (not necessarily enforced by DAC/MAC):

- User/app settings which are subject to FDE, FBE and password authentications (`/data/user_de/<UserId>/<pkg_name>`, `/data/misc/keystore/user_<UserId>`, `/data/misc/gatekeeper/<UserId>` etc.) <sup>([5](https://blog.compass-security.com/2016/10/android-7-0-security-features-direct-boot/), [6](https://source.android.com/security/authentication/gatekeeper))</sup>
- Apps' usage stats (`/data/system/usagestats/<UserId>`)
- System-wide accounts and settings, not all (`/data/system/users/<UserId>`)
- Custom CA certificates (`/data/misc/user/<UserId>`)
- ART profiles data (`/data/misc/profiles/cur/<UserId>`)

---

### CONCLUSION:

So in Android world unlike PC's, everything isn't governed by `uid's`/`gid's`, for a large part we are at the mercy of Android's core framework. But isolation between multiple users does exist, however it depends on what you want to protect from apps.

---

**REFERENCE:**

- [Multiple Users on Android](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user)
- [Linux vs. Android](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=75905973&postcount=2)