# How to access files transferred to device using SimpleSSHD?

Tags: file-transfer, ssh

I am using [SimpleSSHD](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.galexander.sshd/) and doing `scp` to transfer files from my computer to my Redmi phone.

My question is that after I have copied files to `data/user/0/org.galexander.sshd/files`, how do I access them, such as with a File Manager?

Comment: Don't copy files to `/data/user/0/org.galexander.ssh` but to external shared storage `/sdcard`. See similar question for Termux: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218374/218526

Comment: @dhvcc, are you ok with my edit of your question if so please roll back to that revision. It's more straight forward and will be better indexed.  https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/221967/3

Comment: @EvanCarroll hello Evan, I felt that your edit went beyond than fixing the question so I rolled back and made minor fixes. If OP reverts to your version of edit, I would be fine with that. :-)

Comment: @Firelord I know, I (respectfully) disagree with you. The op was clearly confused, having my answer chosen should greenlight me to clarify that. There is no reason to have a muddy question preserved on this site in perpetuity. We can do better for those searching for this, and for those that find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever copy files out of `/sdcard/`, for this task you should leave the files where they are. In order to copy files using SimpleSSHD, simply connect and copy: assuming you've left the default port of `2222` you can do this,

### SCP File Transfer

```
host=192.168.1.228
scp -r "scp://root@${host}:2222//sdcard/DCIM/OpenCamera" .
```

### RSYNC over SSH File Transfer

```
host=192.168.1.228
rsync --progress -ave 'ssh -p 2222' "root@${host}:/sdcard/DCIM/OpenCamera" .
```

Answer (score 0):

On my phone the mountpoint of the external SD card is not `/sdcard/`, but `/storage/XXXX-XXXX/`.

e.g.:

```
HWVNS-H:/data/data/org.galexander.sshd/files $ ls -la /storage/C42F-10F5/
total 480
drwxrwx---   16 root     everybod     32768 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           100 Feb 25 08:56 ..
drwxrwx---    5 root     everybod     32768 Dec 22  2020 Android
drwxrwx---    4 root     everybod     32768 Nov 22 16:36 DCIM
...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That looks like a path to an external SD card, not the internal storage.

Comment: yes, i was talking about my external SD card path. edited above. My phone's android mounts my external SD card to above specified path. i thought /sdcard always means external SD card?