# Running executable files using Termux

Tags: file-permissions, termux

I previously posted on the Linux stack exchange about my problem:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/731882/termux-bash-permission-denied

Suffice to say I've realized that executable files can be run in Termux's home folder (at least that's what I assume `~` is), as well as in `~/storage`, but when I move my compiled file `hello` and `hello.cpp` into `~/storage/shared` the files no longer have permission to be executed:

```
~/storage $ clang++ hello.cpp -o hello
~/storage $ ls -l
total 60
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347    24 Jan 15 12:21 dcim -> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347    28 Jan 15 12:21 downloads -> /storage/emulated/0/Download
-rwx------ 1 u0_a347 u0_a347 53544 Jan 16 14:44 hello
-rw------- 1 u0_a347 u0_a347    88 Jan 16 14:44 hello.cpp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347    26 Jan 15 12:21 movies -> /storage/emulated/0/Movies
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347    25 Jan 15 12:21 music -> /storage/emulated/0/Music
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347    28 Jan 15 12:21 pictures -> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347    19 Jan 15 12:21 shared -> /storage/emulated/0
~/storage $ ./hello
hello world
~/storage $ mv hello hello.cpp shared
~/storage $ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347 24 Jan 15 12:21 dcim -> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347 28 Jan 15 12:21 downloads -> /storage/emulated/0/Download
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347 26 Jan 15 12:21 movies -> /storage/emulated/0/Movies
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347 25 Jan 15 12:21 music -> /storage/emulated/0/Music
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347 28 Jan 15 12:21 pictures -> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a347 u0_a347 19 Jan 15 12:21 shared -> /storage/emulated/0
~/storage $ cd shared
~/storage/shared $ ls -l
total 150
drwxrws--- 2 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Aug  9 21:45 Alarms
drwxrws--x 6 media_rw media_rw  3452 Oct  4 19:30 Android
drwxrws--- 2 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Aug  9 21:45 Audiobooks
drwxrws--- 3 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Oct  4 17:58 DCIM
drwxrws--- 6 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Jan  4 20:33 Documents
drwxrws--- 2 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Jan 16 13:13 Download
drwxrws--- 3 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Aug  9 21:45 Movies
drwxrwsr-x 4 media_rw media_rw  3452 Aug  9 21:45 Music
drwxrws--- 2 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Aug  9 21:45 Notifications
drwxrws--- 3 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Aug  9 21:45 Pictures
drwxrws--- 2 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Aug  9 21:45 Podcasts
drwxrws--- 2 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Aug  9 21:45 Recordings
drwxrws--- 2 u0_a234  media_rw  3452 Aug  9 21:45 Ringtones
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a234  media_rw 53544 Jan 16 14:44 hello
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a234  media_rw    88 Jan 16 14:44 hello.cpp
~/storage/shared $
```

I've heard that external sd cards are mounted with a `noexec` flag, but this is internal storage on my Galaxy Tab S7 FE, so I haven't found anything related to internal storage.

What I'm hoping to be able to do is write C/C++ (and other compiled languages) in another app (say, Acode) in any folder, then using Termux, compile them, and run them. So far I can run HTML/CSS/JS files natively in Acode and I can run Python files stored in `~/storage/shared`, but I'm hoping to increase the flexibility of this setup more.

Comment: In Android's storage model, two apps cannot have a shared directory with executable file permissions. See [How do I access `$HOME/storage` outside of Termux (with a file explorer)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218374/218526).

Comment: In some Android versions it was possible to store and run executables in `/data/local/tmp/`. That directory misses the `x` flag so you can't list it's content but the files were accessible if you knew the path. Not sure about latest Android versions.