# Is completely isolated multi-tenancy possible on Android comparable to Linux?

Tags: multi-user

Is it possible to have on an Android device:

- (permission based or virtual volumes) isolated data storage?
- user specific, independent device usage configuration?
- simple user relogin?

Comment: The Linux user system is used in a totally different way on Android - typically each application has it's own userid. Therefore things like "user relogin" are simply out of scope of Android.

Comment: Stock Android (AOSP) itself doesn't provide any of the three features, except some limited user isolation: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/218526 But some OEMs do provide enhanced security and isolation. Plus Android is based on Linux kernel, so you can use any mechanism including DAC, MAC, namespaces and cgroups on Android too. However integrating with Android framework would be a tough task. Also concept of multi-users is entirely different on Android than on Linux. Your question is very broad, consider narrowing it down to a specific situation.