# How to hide installed app from other app?

Tags: root-access, hidden

If app has storage access, how to hide other installed app from it? App consists of files in different locations. Maybe somehow I can make them unaccessible for other app? If I didn't give root right for detecting app, the only location should be in "Android" folder?

Comment: scroll down to [APPS SPACE USAGE](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216087) every line with **<pkg>** may exist for your app, so every app with root access can look at this locations

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I'm interested in way, how can I hide app from other app which doesn't have root access.

Answer (score 1):

> If app has storage access, how to hide other installed app from it?

Without root access and without any permission (including Storage), any app can [`getInstalledApplications`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstalledApplications(int)) for current user/profile. You need a mod like [XPrivacyLua](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacyLua) to hide apps from other apps. Or isolate apps in user profiles (see [Are multiple-users protected from each other differently than apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/218526)).

> App consists of files in different locations. Maybe somehow I can make them inaccessible for other app? If I didn't give root right for detecting app, the only location should be in "Android" folder?

If I understand correctly you mean that apps private files are already inaccessible to other apps. With `Storage` permission granted apps can only see files created by other apps in shared storage (`/sdcard` and physically external SD card). So if an app creates it's private directory in `/sdcard/Android/`, it does indicate its presence on device. But hiding the private directory won't be helpful as explained earlier. You have to stop the app from using `getInstalledApplications` first.

After that, if you have to grant Storage permission because the app refuses to start otherwise, you can disable Storage access using `appops`:

```
~$ appops set <pkg> READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ignore
~$ appops set <pkg> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ignore
```

If that doesn't work you have to go for a root solution like XPrivacyLua's [`BlockGuardOs.open`](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacyLua/blob/master/examples/BlockGuardOs.open.json) hook or [Storage Redirect](https://sr.rikka.app/guide/#storage-redirect) (it's paid app). I've no affiliation with either. Also [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) on Android 10+ provides better storage isolation.